# A partition layout to persistently store data without the configs/caches/settings

Tags: filesystems, partition, opensuse, home, partition-table

##### Current situtation

I currently use a separate partition mounted on `/home` to be able to install new operating systems without losing the data in `/home`. My current partition layout is:

```
sda      disk 
├─sda1   part /boot/efi
├─sda2   part [SWAP]
├─sda3   part /
└─sda4   part /home
```

##### Problem

The problem is there are lots of caches, config, and settings in `/home/me` which I don't want when I install a new operating system.

##### Workaround

A workaround might be to have another partition containing my necessary **data** mounted somewhere. So, my partitions would be as follows. When installing a new operating system, I would keep just `sda5` mounted on `/somewhere` and format the rest:

```
sda      disk 
├─sda1   part /boot/efi
├─sda2   part [SWAP]
├─sda3   part /
├─sda4   part /home
└─sda5   part /somewhere
```

##### Question

What would be the best mount point for `sda5`, I need to decide about `/somewhere`. Some options are:

- `/data`
- `/var/data`
- ...?

Is there any standard layout for such a case?

Comment: No, there isn't.  You'll have to invent your own.   `/data` is fine.  But....why do this?   Just pick one distro and stick with it.  Everyone has their own preferences, but  (aside from the obvious fact that Debian is the best, and the only one worth using) there really isn't any fundamental difference between them, they all provide access to the same software, either pre-packaged or compile it yourself.   There isn't even anything worthwhile to learn by distro-hopping brand fetishism.

Comment: There is no standard and many opinions on where to mount a data partition. If you mount it in /home or /media it will show in your file browser, some use more than one. One for data that changes a lot and one for media that does not. And then different backup procedures.  If mounted anywhere else it will not, but I prefer that, as I link folders into /home. I prefer /mnt/data, not /mnt. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Comment: @oldfred Thanks for the links =)